# How to access an instance variable without running the function

Tags: python

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num= [0]

    def b(self):
        print("Don't Run")
        self.num= [2]

obj = A()
obj.b()

print(obj.num)

>> Don't Run
>> [2]
```

Here I have a class and I want to access the instance variable `self.num` on function `b`. How can I access the variable without running the `print("Don't Run")`.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your question. What do you mean __access the instance variable self.num on function b__? You can just access `obj.num` without calling `b`. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: But `A` has no instance member `b`...

Comment: `self.num` exists independently of `b`. What `b` does is, as a *side effect*, *change* the value of `self.num`. So are you saying you want one side effect from calling `obj.b` without some other side effect?

Comment: If `b` is the only place where `num` is set to the value you need, then it's unavoidable that you run method `b`. You may be able to monkey-patch `b` with your own function that replicates the logic you need in `b` and avoids the print line? That feels like an ugly option though.

Comment: What's your underlying motivation to want to do that? Without that reason it is hard to guess what you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to avoid printing to the screen, you can redirect `stdout` using [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout).

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
from os import devnull

...

with redirect_stdout(devnull):
  obj.b()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is subclassing:

```py
class B(A):
    def b(self, return _num=False):
        self.num = [2]
        if return_num:
            return self.num
```

So then,

```
>>> b = B()
>>> b.b(return_num=True)
>>> [2]
```